# How can I call C++ OpenGL code inside a C# winform window?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi, opengl

I need to program a windows window with a toolstrip on top, a OpenGL window in the middle and a status line in the bottom:
[image]

I am not to thrilled about programming the GUI elements in win32. I have some experience programming winforms in C# and would like to do this.

The problem then is how do I implement the OpenGL window? 
As I understand OpenTK comes with a GLControl .net component that I can add to a form.

However I already have the OpenGL code that I am going to use in C++.
I would prefer not having to port this to OpenTK but instead use it directly.

How can I achieve this?

I should also explain that my window is not a main window. It is running inside another program that I am implementing a plug-in for.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL context is per-thread state.  If you use OpenTK in C# to make a context current, then any C++ code you call from the same thread will automatically use it.

Comment: Thank you Ben! Are you aware of any limitations/parts of OpenGL that do not work when using this approach? I guess what GLControl does is encapsulate the create OpenGL context described by GIGuru below and as such it should be apart from i.e. not limiting OpenGL in any way?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, that's right.  The only real limitations are associated with context creation in your version of OpenTK -- if your C++ code expects to use a OpenGL 3+ context, it's OpenTK that needs to go through the process of first creating a 2.x context and then overlaying a 3+ context atop that.  Conversely, you don't want OpenTK creating a forward context if your C++ code uses pre-OpenGL 3.0 routines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Isolate your C++ code into a dll.
2. Create a C# application and create an OpenGL context. Make it the current context.
3. Call native functions of your C++ code through the C# code using pinvoke. You can expose one or more entry points that can be called by the C# application.

I have never tried this personally but in theory this should work.